# Saving Purchased Items unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

Im implementing codeless IAP in my app, but I have some questions. I have 5 consumable and one non-consumable, so let's say player bought 100 gold and remove ads and deleted app or changed his/her phone. After reinstalling the game are these purchases restoring or they have to buy again. I want to save the purchase history, so that when the player reinstall the game, can get back what he/she bought. How can I do that. My purchase script is below.

```
if(product != null)
    {
        switch (product.definition.id)
        {
            case "Gold.50":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 50);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "Gold.100":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 100);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "Gold.250":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 250);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "Gold.500":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 500);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "Gold.1000":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 1000);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "removeads":
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Log("Failed");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't dealt with handling consumable items, but the Google play store will send you everything that player has purchased. You don't need to (and shouldn't) save that information locally for durable items (such as remove ads).

Comment: Ok, so I just have remove ads as a non-consumable and I have these gold's as a consumable google play store saving non-consumable purchases but not saving consumable purchases did I understood correctly so if I did understand correctly can I save gold's to a playerpref and through the playerpref can I save it to the google play services cloud save I mean like He bought 100 gold I'm gonna save that 100gold locally and to the cloud save if he sign in with same account he will get the non-consumable automatically and they will get the consumable from the cloud is that possible can do it like this

Comment: Like I said, I don't know how to handle consumable resources. The only time I interfaced with the Google store API was for a project where we did (about 20) durable purchases. There was talk about letting people "buy and redeem" in packs of 5 and I said, "So, virtual currency then? Because that'll be difficult to track, the Play store isn't set up to handle virtual currency" and I was told "No no, not virtual currency." My research *at the time* suggested you'd need to write your own backend server to track those purchases (or suffer the consequences that people could cheat).

Comment: Ok, I managed to save to cloud. But I have another question about non-consumable I didn't quite understand how it works so let's say I bought remove ads and deleted the app and reinstalled when I reinstalled play store automaticlly seing my non-consumable right I mean non-consumable saving it self to the my play store account I know I asked a lot but this is the only script for purchasing something if I need to do something else for non-consumable save I want to know but I think I don't need to do anything else because I think it's saving to play store account

Comment: You don't have to do anything. The play store keeps a record of all your purchases, even if you uninstall the app. For the apple store I there's a method called "restore purchases" (which is for when you get a *new device*) but Google doesn't need it.

Comment: I'm testing purchases. it's not restoring remove ads. when I click to buy again, I'm not getting any response and it's not restoring purchase. it's in alpha test, is this happening because of alpha. I'm saving to cloud I think it will not be problem but I wanna now why it's not restoring purchase

Comment: Google's docs are a pain to browse, so I can't find it right now, but I *know* there's a callback method that gives you a user's prior purchases. [Best I can locate atm](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) and [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html). Its been a year since I worked on that project and don't have the code I wrote. You also have to make sure you *wait for that callback* before checking to see if a thing is purchased.